# C - Difference between the for-loop codes

Tags: c, for-loop

Can someone please explain the difference between these two for-loop codes?

Code 1:

```
int j = 0;
int i;
int n = 8;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Value if I: %d\n",i);
    while (j < n){
        printf("Value of J: %d\n",j);
        j++;
        }
}

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
i = 0 , j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
i = 6
i = 7
```

Code 2:

```
int i;
int n = 8;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Value if I: %d\n",i);
        int j = 0;
    while (j < n){
        printf("Value of J: %d\n",j);
        j++;
        }
}

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
    i = 0 , j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    i = 1 , j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    i = 2 , j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    i = 3 , j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    i = 4 , j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    i = 5 , j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    i = 6 , j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    i = 7 , j = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Why there is a variation among the above two for-loop codes?

Comment: Just think what `j` is in each loop in both examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second code you are resetting j everytime before the while loop, so you get all the values of j for each loop of i.
In the first case instead, once you get to j=8, there are no more resets of this value, so everytime that the while condition is checked it returns FALSE, and it doesn't print it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Well the main difference is that J is created each time you do a new for loop in the second code, compared to being a local variable in the first loop.

This means that after the first loop in the first code J will always be 8 and wont print anymore (because it is already 8 from the first loop)

```
int j = 0;
int i;
int n = 8;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Value if I: %d\n",i);
    while (j < n){
        printf("Value of J: %d\n",j);
        j++;
        }
  j = 0 //THIS RESETS J TO 0 SO IT WILL RUN 8 TIMES PER LOOP
}

}
```

Something like above will work the same as the second block of code

Answer (score 0):

In the second code you initialise `j` to `0` every iteration of the for loop. Thus, your `while()` loop runs `8` times every time the foor loop runs for the second code.

To expand upon that, here is exactly what happens:

```
int i; // i declared
int n = 8; // n declared & initialised
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ // runs 8 times, while i < 8, i starting at 0
        printf("Value if I: %d\n",i); // print
        int j = 0; // declares & intialises j 8 times (every iteration)
    while (j < n){ // runs 8 times j < 8, j starting at 0, for every iteration of the for loop
        printf("Value of J: %d\n",j); // print
        j++; // increment j
        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second loop you set the j value equals to 0 so when while starts, it has to print all numbers from 0 to 8.In your first loop you set j value equals to 0 once so while execute the commands and in the next loop while is not executing because j value is 8, you don't set j=0 in every loop as the second one.